# Upload Picture in Php

Tags: php, image, upload

I am trying to allow user to upload picture to my site, I know how upload files in php. but my problem is I want to be able to get the name of the person who uploads the picture... How would I be able show each person's name to next to the image he/she posted

Comment: Do you want to add some code to the question?

Comment: In your database, do you save anything related to the picture? I.e. path, size, views, likes, uploader, that sort of stuff? If not, rethink your datamodel and make the necessary changes.

Answer (score 0):

When a user logs in, store his user id in a [session](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.session.php). Foresee a foreign key 'user_id' in the images table and insert the user id of the logged in user in this table along with the link to the image when he uploads the image.

When displaying the images, you can query the uploaders name of each image.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure how your site works but when users logins to the site, you can store their usernames through session. You can use these sessions to store, embed or get usernames.